# Automapper ForAllPropertyMaps not working

Tags: c#, automapper

Within an AutoMapper Profile I'm trying to set up a default property map for a property "CrudOpMut" so that I don't have to specify in each CreateMap:

```
ForAllPropertyMaps(pm => pm.DestinationProperty.Name.Equals("CrudOpMut"), (pm, o) => o.Ignore());

CreateMap<IDmoAccountHousehold, DtoMfcAccountHousehold>()
    //.ForMember(a => a.CrudOpMut, o => o.Ignore())
    ;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
==============================
IDmoAccountHousehold -> DtoMfcAccountHousehold (Destination member list)
DomainModels.Interface.ThankQ.IDmoAccountHousehold -> 
DataTransferObjects.Concrete.Migrate.MissionForce.DtoMfcAccountHousehold (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
CrudOpMut

at AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already built in:

```
configuration.AddGlobalIgnore("CrudOpMut");
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Since I'm doing this in a profile I can just do AddGlobalIgnore("CrudOpMut");

Comment: It's hard to tell without the code. If you can make a repro, I'll look into it.